# Не получается спарсить данные из тега

Tags: python, html, парсер, beautiful-soup, веб-скрейпинг

Не получается залезть в этот тег, выдает None

```
<app-root urlvalue="//search.worldbank.org/api/v2/procnotices?format=json&amp;apilang=en&amp;fl=*&amp;id=OP00231428&amp;apilang=en" _nghost-c0="" ng-version="5.2.4"><app-post _ngcontent-c0="" _nghost-c1=""><section _ngcontent-c1="" id="overview">
```

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
headers = {
'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/116.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
def get_data(links):

       r = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
       soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
       parbase_section = soup.find('div', class_='projects_angular_procurement parbase section')
       id = parbase_section.find('p', class_='document-info')
       print(id)

get_data(['https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement-detail/OP00231428'])
```

Вот сам [сайт](https://projects.worldbank.org/en/projects-operations/procurement-detail/OP00231428) мне нужно вытянуть эти данные [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ну а код ваш где?

Comment: @strawdog извиняюсь, отредактировал

Comment: `projects_angular_procurement` ведёт на данные всей страницы. Что вы спарсить то хотите?

Comment: @DiMithras на прикрепленном фото указано, а в своем коде я пытался спарсить айди

Answer (score 2):

```py
import requests
import json
response = requests.post(
    'https://search.worldbank.org/api/v2/procnotices',
    params={
        'format': 'json',
        'apilang': 'en',
        'id': 'OP00231428',
#        'fl': ','.join(['project_name', 'project_ctry_name']) # Это если захочется ограничить набор полей
    }
)
with open('response.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    json.dump(
        response.json(),
        f,
        ensure_ascii=False,
        indent=2
    )
```

###### response.json

```json
{
  "rows": 10,
  "os": "0",
  "page": "1",
  "total": "1",
  "procnotices": [
    {
      "id": "OP00231428",
      "notice_type": "Request for Expression of Interest",
      "noticedate": "16-Aug-2023",
      "notice_lang_name": "English",
      "notice_status": "Published",
      "submission_deadline_date": "2023-08-23T00:00:00Z",
      "submission_deadline_time": "17:30",
      "project_ctry_name": "Timor-Leste",
      "project_id": "P166744",
      "project_name": "Basic Education Strengthening and Transformation Project",
      "bid_reference_no": "031-2023/IDV/BEST/TL",
      "bid_description": "Finance Management Specialist",
      "procurement_group": "CS",
      "procurement_method_code": "INDV",
      "procurement_method_name": "Individual Consultant Selection",
      "contact_address": "Dili, Timor Leste",
      "contact_ctry_name": "Timor-Leste",
      "contact_email": "antoninhopires48a@gmail.com",
      "contact_name": "Antoninho  Pires",
      "contact_organization": "Ministry of Education Youth and Sport",
      "contact_phone_no": "+67077230210",
      "submission_date": "2023-08-16T00:00:00Z",
      "notice_text": "<p><strong>REQUEST FOR EXPRESSIONS OF INTEREST (INDIVIDUAL CONSULTING SERVICES)</strong></p><p><strong>(RE-ADVERTISED)</strong></p><p><strong>TIMOR-LESTE</strong></p><p><strong>BASIC</strong><strong> </strong><strong>EDUCATION</strong><strong> </strong><strong>STRENGTHENING</strong><strong> </strong><strong>AND</strong><strong> </strong><strong>TRANSFORMATION</strong><strong> </strong><strong>(BEST)</strong><strong> </strong><strong>PROJECT</strong></p><p>Grant No.: TF 0B2130</p><p><strong>Project</strong><strong> </strong><strong>ID</strong>.: P166744</p><p><strong>Position</strong><strong> </strong><strong>Types</strong>: Individual Consultant</p><p><strong>Assignment Ref. No: 031-2023/INDV/BEST/TL&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;</strong></p><p><strong>Assignment Title: FINANCIAL MANAGEMENT SPECIALIST</strong><strong> </strong></p><p>The Ministry of Education (MoE) of the Democratic Republic of Timor-Leste has received financing from the World Bank toward the cost of the Basic Education Strengthening and Transformation (BEST) Project, and intends to apply part of the proceeds for consulting services.</p><p>The consulting services (&ldquo;the Services&rdquo;) include individual consultant services position of Financial Management Specialist. The duration of the assignment is Initially 12 months (Three months of probational period), extendible until the completion of the project based on satisfactory performance. The candidates are expected to start working in early September 2023.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>The detailed Terms of References (TORs) for these assignments can be obtained at the address given below<em>.</em></p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>The Ministry of Education (MoE) now invites eligible individuals (&ldquo;Consultants&rdquo;) to indicate their interest in providing the Services. Interested Consultants should provide information demonstrating that they have the required qualifications and relevant experience to perform the Services (attach curriculum vitae with description of experience in similar assignments, similar conditions, etc.). Firms&rsquo; staff may express interest through the employing firm for the assignment and, under such situation, only the experience and qualifications of individuals shall be considered in the selection process. The criteria for selecting the Consultant are described in the Terms of Reference.</p><p>The attention of interested Consultants (including firms) is drawn to paragraph 3.14, 3.16 and 3.17 &nbsp;of the World Bank&rsquo;s <em>Procurement Regulations for IPF Borrowers </em>July 2016 (4th edition as of November 2020), (&ldquo;the Regulations&rdquo;), setting forth the World Bank&rsquo;s policy on conflict of interest.</p><p><strong><em>Interested eligible consultants may obtain details of the Terms of Reference from MoE, PMIU BEST Project at the address given below during office hours i.e. 8:00 a.m. to 17.00</em></strong></p><p><strong><em>p.m. Mondays to Fridays or visit </em></strong><strong><em>https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ZRCfXPyLrpEa6H0_qNc8Z8DCr_STK3z4/view?usp=sharing</em></strong></p><p>The email subject heading must be: <strong>MoE BEST Project-&nbsp; (position name).</strong></p><p>Expressions of interest must be delivered in a written form to the address below in person or by e- mail by Close of Business hours as per the table below: Application documents received after this deadline will not be considered for processing.</p><p>&nbsp;</p><table border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tbody><tr><td style=\"border-color:black; height:13.85pt; vertical-align:top; width:31.35pt\"><p><strong>No.</strong></p></td><td style=\"border-color:black; height:13.85pt; vertical-align:top; width:211.45pt\"><p><strong>Position title</strong></p></td><td style=\"border-color:black; height:13.85pt; vertical-align:top; width:129.1pt\"><p><strong>Position</strong><strong> </strong><strong>Number</strong></p></td><td style=\"border-color:black; height:13.85pt; vertical-align:top; width:113.9pt\"><p><strong>Deadline</strong><strong> </strong><strong>of</strong><strong> </strong><strong>Application</strong></p></td></tr><tr><td style=\"border-color:black; height:13.75pt; vertical-align:top; width:31.35pt\"><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>1</strong></p></td><td style=\"height:13.75pt; vertical-align:top; width:211.45pt\"><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>Financial Management Specialist </strong></p></td><td style=\"height:13.75pt; vertical-align:top; width:129.1pt\"><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>031-2023/INDV/BEST/TL</strong></p></td><td style=\"height:13.75pt; vertical-align:top; width:113.9pt\"><p>&nbsp;</p><p><strong>August 23, 2023</strong></p><p><strong>&nbsp;</strong></p></td></tr></tbody></table><p>BEST- Project Implementation Management Unit (PIMU)</p><p>&nbsp;Minist&eacute;rio da Educa&ccedil;&atilde;o (MoE)</p><p>&nbsp;Rua Villa Verde, Dili, Timor-Leste</p><p>Attention: Apolinario M.M. do Rego, BEST Project Manager</p><p>Tel: +670 &nbsp;77410701</p><p>E-mail: bestproject861@gmail.com &nbsp;or alternatively to apoli060278@gmail.com</p><p>Dili, 16th of August 2023</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p><u>Antoninho Pires</u></p><p>Director General Administration and Financing Management/</p><p>BEST Project Supervisor -MoE</p><p>&nbsp;</p><p>&nbsp;</p>"
    }
  ]
}
```

> Если, все же, Вам остро необходимо именно распарсить HTML, то обратите внимание на библиотеки `selenium` или `html-requests`. Загрузите с их помощью страницу (они позволяют дождаться прогрузки java-script) и уже потом супом по хтмл